# Regex in logstash mutate gsub to replace a character in a string

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to get double quotes (placed at random places) from a string replaced with something else.
This is the logline-

```
msg="AUT30544: User chose to proceed on the sign-in notification page "Sign-In Notification Message""
```

Actually this was part of `KV` parsing in logstash's filter section. If you notice there is a quoted string inside of a string that itself is in double-quotes.

However, Below string gets correctly parsed in `KV`-

```
msg="AUT23278: User Limit realm restrictions successfully passed for /google_auth "
```

Now I created a regex to remove the double-quotes in problematic string-
https://regex101.com/r/o00oot/1/
Applied it in logstash but nothing changed.
Below is my config file-

```
input {
        tcp {
                port => 1301
        }
}
filter {
                if "type=vpn" in [message] {
                        dissect {
                                mapping => { "message" => "%{reserved} id=firewall %{message1}" }
                        }
                        #mutate { gsub => ["message1",':'," "] }
                        #mutate { gsub => ["message1",'"',''] }
                        mutate {gsub => ["msg","(.*)\"(.*)\"(\")", "\1 '\2 '\3"] }
                        kv { source => "message1"  value_split => "=" whitespace => "strict" }   #field_split => " " remove_char_value => '"' }
                        geoip { source => "src"  }
                # \/ end of if vpn type log
                }
        else { drop {}  }
}
```

A similar logline that I could capture using `tcpdump` is-

```
<134>Oct  2 11:24:45 1xx.xx.43.101 1 2021-10-02T11:24:45+05:30 canopus.domain1.com2 PulseSecure: - - - id=firewall time="2021-10-02 11:24:45" pri=6 fw=172.20.43.101 vpn=ive user=user1 realm="google_auth" roles="" proto=auth src=2xx.176.114.94 dst= dstname= type=vpn op= arg="" result= sent= rcvd= agent="" duration= msg="AUT30544: User chose to proceed on the sign-in notification page "Sign-In Notification Message""
```

The stdout of same kind of message on stdout. I can see the double-quotes being escaped but still they create problem in parsing.

```
{
          "type" => "vpn",
          "user" => "user1",
            "fw" => "1xx.xx.43.101",
          "host" => "1xx.xx.4.63",
         "realm" => "google_auth",
           "src" => "1xx.66.50.112",
          "port" => 33003,
      "@version" => "1",
       "message" => "<13>Oct  2 11:54:39 1xx.xx.43.101 396 <134>1 2021-10-02T11:54:39+05:30 canopus.domain1.com2 PulseSecure: - - - id=firewall time=\"2021-10-02 11:54:39\" pri=6 fw=1xx.xx.43.101 vpn=ive user=user1 realm=\"google_auth\" roles=\"\" proto=auth src=1xx.66.50.112 dst= dstname= type=vpn op= arg=\"\" result= sent= rcvd= agent=\"\" duration= msg=\"AUT30544: User chose to proceed on the sign-in notification page \"Sign-In Notification Message\"\"",
         "geoip" => {
              "location" => {
            "lon" => 77.5937,
            "lat" => 12.9719
        },
```

If someone knows a `KV` plugin's native solution to this problem, I dont need to go through hassles of `regex` in `gsub`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use `kv` on whole message as you have, try to split it up so you get key/value part of the message in separate field and then use `kv` on it. That being said, I would suggest you to skip using `gsub` here completely because there is option called `trim_value` for `kv` filter.

With that option your configuration would look something like this. Disclaimer, this is not tested, maybe you'll have to play with regex inside of `trim_value`, but this is easier way to handle it.

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 1301
    }
}

filter {
    if "type=vpn" in [message] {
        dissect {
                mapping => { "message" => "%{reserved} id=firewall %{message1}" }
        }
        kv {
            source => "message1" 
            value_split => "="
            whitespace => "strict"
            trim_value => "\\\""
        }
        geoip {
            source => "src"
        }
    }
    else {
        drop { } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Filip. I added the `trim_value` , but it didn't help.

Comment: Which variations did you try and what was the result?

Comment: I exactly applied `trim_value => "\\\""` but still I can see that the double quotes are not getting escaped

Comment: I like to make changes like this incrementally, when you gsub, index the new msg/field to elasticsearch or print to file, then explore it further either on the file or on Kibana to see the changes between the old and new fields.